# Why does angularjs site works on desktop but not on mobile?

Tags: angularjs, mobile

Can anybody explain why this site (using angularjs) works in desktop but not in mobile?

The app allows searching for a timezone then when selected displays the time. On desktop it works but on mobile searching fails.

[Visit site here](http://wiz.dx.am/world-clock/clock.html)

Comment: well I checked on my mobile and works...

Comment: well searching for timezone doesn't work on mobile